# can we use nanoscroller for horizontal scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling, nanoscroller

Does anyone have any idea if we can use nanoscroller for horizontal scrolls as well?

I have been searching in google but unable to find any relevant information on this.

I have implemented nanoscroller it works fine with vertical scrolls and scrool bar doesnt appear for scrolling horizontally.

Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: At the time of writing this Nano still has no support for horizontal scrollbar, but [Antiscroll](https://github.com/Automattic/antiscroll) has :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer here :

https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS

Its mentioned that the team is still working on horizontal scrolling.

So, now my question would be, if anyone has a work-around for this, please suggest.

Thanks.